# runtime complexity of this function

Tags: javascript, big-o

```
function subset(array1, array2) {
    const array1Set = new Set(array1);
    const array2Set = new Set(array2);

    for (const value of array2Set) {
        if (!array1Set.has(value)) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    
    return true;
}
```

Is it `O(n)`? because of the size of the array.

Answer (score 0):

It is indeed `O(n)` as you iterate the keys (or array) in `array2Set` and queries to the set are `O(1)` so `O(n)` total.